# .gitignore missing from repo managed with VS Code

Tags: windows-10, git, visual-studio-code

I have Windows 10 and I've cloned the repo using Visual Studio Code. There is no .gitignore in the main folder and I have already configured the folder options to show hidden files and even to show the know extensions.

Comment: Are you sure this file exists in the repository you've cloned?

Comment: shouldn't it be autogenerated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there's no `.gitignore` in the repository you're cloning, then there won't be one in your cloned repository. That's how cloning works, it's a perfect mirror of the original repository. Otherwise cloning itself would create differences between original and clone.

`.gitignore` is not mandatory. If there's none, nothing is ignored. The file is not autogenerated too because usually (exceptions apply) there's no point in having and empty one and git doesn't automagically know what you want to ignore (it doesn't care about files' content, it just tracks them as they are).

Related trivia:

- `.gitignore` can be placed in any directory in the repository. Its contents affect that directory and its subdirectories. You can have multiple `.gitignore`s in a single repo. All `.gitignore`s are taken into account (respecting their scope).
- There's also `.git/info/exclude` which works like `.gitignore`, but isn't committed. You can use it if you want to ignore something only locally.

Comment: Thanks, it clarified a lot!